# Applying Write Protection Password on USB Drive (Not on Read )

Tags: usb, password-protection

I want to password-protect write and format operations of a USB Flash drive but also want to access the USB Drive with read-only access without any password. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the USB flash drive have a physical read only switch? If so, use it.

Comment: @EBGreen i dont have physical read only switch

Comment: [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15219/is-there-such-thing-as-a-password-enforced-write-protected-flash-drive) has you covered. As far as I know there isn't a way to achieve this

Comment: @Alone do you want to prevent accidental writes to the flash drive or do you want to protect it from being compromised by others who have physical access to the flash drive?

Comment: @danzel in my office environment , we want our IT  support personnel restricted to write data or additional tools or software in USB Drives provided to them. we want them to use the tools or software only provided by us .

Comment: Fire a couple that violate procedures. I know that sounds harsh but ultimately you are trying to fix a behavior problem with technology which is almost always a losing proposition.

Comment: @Alone how would that prevent people to bring their own flash drive or download and install different software? Seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me because you are really looking for a way to prevent people from installing software other than that provided by you.

Comment: @danzel You're probably right. And a read-only pendrive wouldn't really be able to install software on an computer or transfer the executables to the PC.

Comment: A read only USB most definitely could be used to install software on a computer or transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you **can't achieve that**. You could:

- Encrypt your whole drive with [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).

Encrypt your flash drive gives you protection but you need to input the password in read/write operations which doesn't suits your needs.

- Have a flash-drive with a physical read-only switch

This offers what you want but because it's a physical switch it will be easy to override read-only protection (and of course it isn't a password method).

Comment: Calderia are you sure USB with read only switch ,resolve my issue?

Comment: No. Based on the comment that you posted above ot will not.